# Translation of "be nice" (said to children)

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

In English, if children are misbehaving, someone might correct them by saying, "Be nice!" How is this normally said in Spanish?

Answer (score 6):

In Spain, the most common ways that come to my mind are:

> **¡Pórtate bien!**
>
> **¡Sé bueno!**
>
> **¡Compórtate!**

I would say that "pórtate bien" is more common probably.

Comment: Same in Argentina (only different stress, because of voseo: "portate bien" = "comportate")

Comment: @leonbloy yeah ¡Compórtate! is also another one, thanks

Comment: I had a friend from Mexico who commonly said "Pórtate bien, chica," when we were saying goodbye.